# setOnClickListener not working in ActivityMain.java

Tags: android

`setOnClickListener` throws an error as identifier required, should I import any specific package?

```
package com.example.work.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.*;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//initialize the button
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
// set the button action
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        goToSecondPage();
    }
});
}
```

Help me solve this issue! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your listener code inside `onCreate` or other function & call from `onCreate`.
Like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   //initialize the button
   Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
   // set the button action
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        goToSecondPage();
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Button` initialize and set `OnClickListener` should be in `onCreate` method. 
Like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       //initialize the button
       Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
       // set the button action
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               goToSecondPage();
           }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: good answer take my vote. now you need only 1 point to cross 3000 reputation :D

Comment: @Srikanth which answer helped you to solve this issue?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed thank you, im working on calculator app, all the buttons overlap on one another, how to allign it properly, should i edit the xml file?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed sure! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in java..

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

/**
 * this method initialized all view controls.
 */
private void init() {

    btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
}

/**
 * this method define all view controls listener.
 */
private void setListener() {
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            goToSecondPage();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You forgot to call `init()`  and `setListener()` inside `onCreate()`

Answer (score -1):

Try this `onCreate` method:

```
//initialize the button
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

// set the button action
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    goToSecondPage();
  }
})
```